# Writing Unit Test for my Class based views which also require LoginRequiredMixin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-unittest

I have one ListView and one DetailView and both requires LoginRequiredMixin. Now i want to write unit test for these class based views. Can somebody help me with this. I want to test the template, context as well as right view is called. My Tests.py Looks like this:-

from django.test import TestCase, Client

from django.urls import reverse,resolve

from django.test.client import RequestFactory

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from teams.models import Teams

from teams.views import TeamListView, TeamDetailView

class TestTeamsView(TestCase):

```
def setUp(self):
    self.factory = RequestFactory()

def test_list_view(self):
    request = self.factory.get(reverse('teams:team_list'))
    response = TeamListView.as_view()(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    print(response.status_code)
```

I am getting Response:

if not request.user.is_authenticated:

AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution and its like this:

```
from django.test.client import RequestFactory

from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser


class TestTeamsView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='test1',
            email='abc1@gmail.com',
            first_name='t',
            last_name='u',
            password='password'
        )
    def test_team_list_view_with_valid_user(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/team/')
        request.user = self.user
        response = TeamListView.as_view()(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.template_name[0], 'teams/teams_list.html')
    
    def test_team_list_view_with_anonymous_user(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/team/')
        request.user = AnonymousUser()
        response = TeamListView.as_view()(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,302)
```